# Dojo Menu.bindDomNode() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, dojo

I'm writing a simple dojo menu and trying to attach it to a Dijit.Tree node, which is subject to the click handler. Could someone please help? I'm getting the error :

**> Uncaught TypeError: nodeControlMenu.bindDomNode is not a function(anonymous function)**

```
dojo.connect(tree, 'onClick', function(item, node, event){

    var addNodeMenuItem = new MenuItem({
        label : "Add Node"
    });
    var removeNodeMenuItem = new MenuItem({
        label : "Remove Node"
    });

    var nodeControlMenu = new Menu({
        targetNodeIds : [node]
    });


    nodeControlMenu.addChild(addNodeMenuItem);
    nodeControlMenu.addChild(removeNodeMenuItem);
    nodeControlMenu.bindDomNode(node);
});
```

Comment: What version of dojo are you on? It looks like  <= 1.6

Comment: I'm using the latest one. The code looks that way because I couldn't find very many tutorials or books, so I've been getting by with bits and pieces. It's a shame, I know.

Comment: I think this api may be old. Sorry.

Comment: Could you point me to the more recent one?

Comment: If you use the latest Version of dojo, which is 1.10, you should use it strikt. dojo.connect is deprecated and you should use "dojo/on" instead. Your code then would look like : on(tree,"Click",function(....){});

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `bindDomNode` is superfluous - specifying `targetNodeIds` effectively [does the same thing](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.4/Menu.js#L92).

However, this doesn't explain why your code claims `bindDomNode` is not a function, since it certainly is defined on `dijit/Menu`'s prototype.  Without further context given, I would suspect that perhaps you have some mismatched dependencies and factory function argument names?